# WPF Window custom event creating and binding to ICommand

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, data-binding

This is WPF/MVVM application. There is some code in code behind **MainWindow.xaml.cs** that should produce custom event and it is required to report the fact (maybe with args) of this event to view model class (MainWindowViewModel.cs).

For ex. I declared RoutedEvent TimerEvent in **partial class MainWindow** but I can't binding to view model command due to this event not available on xaml code. Error: Timer is not recognized or is not accessible.

How can this problem be solved? Thanks!

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var timer = new Timer();
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            timer.Interval = 5000;
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            RaiseTimerEvent();
        }

        // Create a custom routed event
        public static readonly RoutedEvent TimerEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
            "Timer", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MainWindow));

        // Provide CLR accessors for the event
        public event RoutedEventHandler Timer
        {
            add => AddHandler(TimerEvent, value);
            remove => RemoveHandler(TimerEvent, value);
        }
        
        void RaiseTimerEvent()
        {
            var newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(MainWindow.TimerEvent);
            RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
        }
    }
```

```
<Window x:Class="CustomWindowEvent.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomWindowEvent"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="400"
        Timer="{Binding TimerCommand}">   // THIS PRODUCE ERROR Timer is not recognized or is not accessible.

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            <Button Width="75"
                    Height="24"
                    Content="Run"
                    Command="{Binding RunCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to bind an event to a command...? That's not how it works.

Comment: How can I report to ViewModel about any custom event in partial class MainWindow?

Comment: Please refer to my answer.

Comment: The timer should be implemented in the view model class directly.

Comment: @BionicCode, this is just for example. In real code there is  some algorithms that using window handle.

Comment: I see. It was just meant to give you the option to invert the communication flow. The view model should not care about events taking place in the view. You know this. And to "cheat" you are trying to convert the event into a direct command/method invokation. But the source is still a view event (other than an actor triggered event like a button click to start a data operation). It seems you should rather update dependency properties and bind them to the view model. But I can't really criticise your approach, I don't have the information. It's just that your requirement could indicate a smell.

Comment: Maybe the logic doesn't even belong to the view. It's also possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot bind an `ICommand` property to an event just like that.

When your window raises the command, you might invoke the command programmatically:

```
void RaiseTimerEvent()
{
    var newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(MainWindow.TimerEvent);
    RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);

    var vm = this.DataContext as MainWindowViewModel;
    if (vm != null)
        vm.TimerCommand.Execute(null);
}
```

The other option is to use an `EventTrigger` and an `InvokeCommandAction` from the [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/) package to invoke the command using XAML:

```
<Window .. xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Timer" >
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TimerCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Window>
```

Please refer to [this blog post](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for answer and for your blog!